# Look for new versions of dependencies

Tags: maven-2

Is there any way to make maven look for new versions of dependencies?

for example, i have
        
            commons-lang
            commons-lang
            2.3

version 2.4 could be out, I dont know. i'd rather not check is manually(by writting 2.4 in this case), because i have many dependencies. I think i saw some trick to make maven use latest version.

Comment: see also: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30571/how-do-i-tell-maven-to-use-the-latest-version-of-a-dependency

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> I think i saw some trick to make maven use latest version.

Yes, there are special version numbers to handle this:

> When you depend on a plugin or a dependency, you can use the a version value of LATEST or RELEASE. LATEST refers to the latest released or snapshot version of a particular artifact, the most recently deployed artifact in a particular repository. RELEASE refers to the last non-snapshot release in the repository.

(Excerpt from [Maven, the definitive guide](http://books.sonatype.com/maven-book/reference/pom-relationships-sect-pom-syntax.html#pom-relationships-sect-latest-release))

PS: although the book also mentions this as a "not-so-best" practice...

Comment: It's better to use the "versions" plugin and upgrade your dependencies in a controlled manner, rather than _always_ having the latest version.

Comment: The link to http://books.sonatype.com/maven-book/reference/pom-relationships-sect-pom-syntax.html#pom-relationships-sect-latest-release is dead.

Comment: Using LATEST is fine for developer builds.  However, to ensure repeatable builds after checking-in, use the versions plugin, and get the CI job to check those pom files into a branch.  That way, you'll always have locked-down dependencies in your pom.xml files (providing they're not SNAPSHOTs of course!), should you ever need to patch/fix that precise build in production.

Answer (score 29):

`mvn versions:display-dependency-updates`

Will show dependency updates

Read more here: [display-dependency-updates](http://mojohaus.org/versions-maven-plugin/examples/display-dependency-updates.html)

Answer (score 7):

```
mvn versions:display-dependency-updates
```

Don't change versions automatically. Dependency updates show also beta/alfa releases eg. for hibernate

Additionally use the following command for plugin updates:

```
mvn versions:display-plugin-updates
```

Comment: I would like to add `mvn versions:display-property-updates` to the list.

Answer (score 0):

Yah you can't make it look for newer versions of dependencies. What you can do is look at the repo, try a search at http://www.mvnrepository.com/

Really you shouldn't want Maven doing this. It could cause a lot of nasty issues. Sometimes backwards compatibility can break even in point releases.