# Maven check for updated dependencies in repository

Tags: maven, dependencies, version, maven-2, maven-3

Is there a Maven plugin that allows you to check if there are newer versions of dependencies available in the repository?

Say, you are using dependency X with version 1.2. Now a new version of X is released with version 1.3. I'd like to know, based on the dependencies used in my project, which dependencies have newer versions available.

Comment: Related question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/431332/.

Answer (score 347, accepted):

The [Maven Versions plugin](http://www.mojohaus.org/versions-maven-plugin/) and it's [`display-dependency-updates`](http://www.mojohaus.org/versions-maven-plugin/display-dependency-updates-mojo.html) mojo are what you're looking for:

```
mvn versions:display-dependency-updates
```

Here is what the output looks like:

```
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Building Build Helper Maven Plugin
[INFO]    task-segment: [versions:display-dependency-updates]
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] [versions:display-dependency-updates]
[INFO]
[INFO] The following dependency updates are available:
[INFO]   org.apache.maven:maven-artifact ........................ 2.0 -> 2.0.9
[INFO]   org.apache.maven:maven-plugin-api ...................... 2.0 -> 2.0.9
[INFO]   org.apache.maven:maven-project ....................... 2.0.2 -> 2.0.9
[INFO]   org.codehaus.plexus:plexus-utils ....................... 1.1 -> 1.5.6
[INFO]
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD SUCCESSFUL
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 17 seconds
[INFO] Finished at: Fri Aug 15 10:46:03 IST 2008
[INFO] Final Memory: 10M/167M
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Comment: Thanks Pascal. That's what I was looking for. Though, for Spring version 3.0.1.RELEASE it reports a newer version of 2.5.6. Maybe a bug in the plugin?

Comment: @Felix You're welcome. Regarding the Spring artifact, I wonder if the problem is not due to the fact that Spring is not following ["the rule"](http://docs.codehaus.org/display/MAVEN/Dependency+Mediation+and+Conflict+Resolution): version should be 3.0.1-RELEASE, not 3.0.1.RELEASE. In other words, I'm not sure it's a bug (I mean, sure, I'd expect the plugin to report 3.0.1.RELEASE as newer too, but I'm not sure this would be accepted as a bug).

Comment: Checking updates `maven-plugin-api` can also be used to check newer versions of Maven itself since a new version of this dependency is released for every Maven releases.

Comment: That's good to know. However, is there a way to have this report when we build a project instead of having to type that command explicitely ?

Comment: How would I have it only tell me about direct dependencies that can be updated? I don't want to be told about all the transitive dependencies I could update...

Comment: WARNING: IF you have a big project,  this will take forever.

Comment: There is no way to auto-update, like `mvn versions:set` changes the poms? Clearly, it has to be tested afterwards, but would be very helpful

Answer (score 41):

In projects with a large number of dependancies, you sometimes keep your versions in a properties section.

```
    <properties>
        <assertj.version>3.15.0</assertj.version>
        <aws-sdk.version>1.11.763</aws-sdk.version>
        <cxf.version>3.3.6</cxf.version>
```

In the case where you are only interested in updates to those versions, you can use the following command

`mvn versions:display-property-updates`

This gives a more condensed view and only returns the versions you need to update in the properties section.

Comment: Underrated answer.

Comment: This seemed to miss 90% of the properties I have that define versions.

Comment: @ArtOfWarfare Also, for projects using dependencies like Spring

Answer (score 38):

If you want to receive email notifications when newer artifacts versions are available on [Maven Central](http://search.maven.org/) you can create an account on [artifact-listener](https://www.artifact-listener.org/) and choose which artifact you want to follow.
You can either search manually for artifacts or directly upload your pom.xml.

You will periodically received notifications like this one (available in english and french for now) :

[image: Maven artifact listener]

Answer (score 22):

The [VersionEye](http://www.versioneye.com) Maven Plugin is doing the same: [versioneye_maven_plugin](https://github.com/versioneye/versioneye_maven_plugin).

VersionEye can notify you about new versions on Maven Repositories, too. It is a language agnostic tool and beside Java it supports 7 other languages. Beside the simple follow/notify feature it can also directly monitor GitHub and BitBucket repositories and notify your about out-dated dependencies in your projects.

[image]

There is also a [REST JSON API](https://www.versioneye.com/api), for tool integrations.

By the way, I'm the dude who started this project. Let me know if you have questions.

Comment: The project is closed :(

Answer (score 14):

The ideal way to do it is to set dependency versions as properties in pom.xml and then running the below command to get the updated versions for your specific/custom dependencies.

```
<properties>
    <java.version>1.8</java.version>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    <project.reporting.outputEncoding>UTF-8</project.reporting.outputEncoding>
    <skip.tests>true</skip.tests>
    <spring-cloud-gcp.version>1.2.3.RELEASE</spring-cloud-gcp.version>
    <spring-cloud.version>Hoxton.SR6</spring-cloud.version>
    <spring-cloud-stream-schema.version>2.2.1.RELEASE</spring-cloud-stream-schema.version>
    <confluent.version>5.5.1</confluent.version>
    <avro.version>1.10.0</avro.version>
    <janino.version>3.1.2</janino.version>
    <swagger.version>2.9.2</swagger.version>
    <google-cloud-logging-logback.version>0.118.1-alpha</google-cloud-logging-logback.version>
    <spring-cloud-stream-binder-kafka.version>3.0.6.RELEASE</spring-cloud-stream-binder-kafka.version>
</properties>
```

```
mvn versions:display-property-updates


[INFO] The following version properties are referencing the newest available version:
[INFO]   ${avro.version} .............................................. 1.10.0
[INFO]   ${spring-cloud-stream-schema.version} ................. 2.2.1.RELEASE
[INFO]   ${janino.version} ............................................. 3.1.2
[INFO] The following version property updates are available:
[INFO]   ${spring-cloud-gcp.version} .......... 1.2.3.RELEASE -> 1.2.5.RELEASE
[INFO]   ${google-cloud-logging-logback.version}  0.118.1-alpha -> 0.118.2-alpha
[INFO]   ${spring-cloud-stream-binder-kafka.version}  3.0.6.RELEASE -> 3.0.8.RELEASE
[INFO]   ${confluent.version} ................................. 5.5.1 -> 6.0.0
[INFO]   ${swagger.version} ................................... 2.9.2 -> 3.0.0
[INFO]   ${spring-cloud.version} .................... Hoxton.SR6 -> Hoxton.SR8
[INFO] 
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD SUCCESS
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time:  3.572 s
[INFO] Finished at: 2020-10-06T09:35:08-07:00
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Another way to achieve this is by executing the command `mvn versions:display-dependency-updates` but the problem I face with this approach is that it also shows me updates for the nested dependencies which are not too useful for me.

Answer (score 3):

You can use the Versions Maven Plugin[1] to generate reports in your Maven site to get a list of possible updates. With regard to Spring's irregularity, it appears to use the Mercury versioning system[2]. When configuring the Versions plugin, you can add a special rule for Spring stuff:

1. http://mojo.codehaus.org/versions-maven-plugin/
2. http://docs.codehaus.org/display/MAVEN/Mercury+Version+Ranges

Comment: could you provide an example?

Answer (score 2):

I might be a bit late to join the party but a more clear way to get more readable html file or a xml file as report which can be taken for further automation using:

```
mvn versions:dependency-updates-report
```

This report plugin not just shows more comprehensive details on updates but also has options to update to latest versions. You can find the  [documentation](https://www.mojohaus.org/versions/versions-maven-plugin/dependency-updates-report-mojo.html) for it to use various parameters.

Comment: This is much better as it shows both the newest minor and major versions. Sadly, I didn't find how to get an aggregated report.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [MvnCheck](https://github.com/AlexisJehan/MvnCheck), a command line tool, which is standalone unlike the *Versions Maven Plugin*. It also works with Gradle projects.

Output example:

```
2 build file(s) found, checking for artifact updates

my-gradle-project\build.gradle
[COMPILE ONLY] com.google.guava:guava 31.0-android -> 31.1-android
1 artifact update(s) available

my-maven-project\pom.xml
[DEPENDENCY] org.apache.commons:commons-lang3 3.10 -> 3.12.0
[BUILD PLUGIN] org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-compiler-plugin 3.10.0 -> 3.10.1
2 artifact update(s) available

2/2 build file(s) checked, 3 artifact update(s) available
```

**Disclaimer**: I am the author of *MvnCheck*.