# maven Missing artifact javax.transaction:jta:jar:1.0.1B

Tags: java, spring, maven, dependency-injection, artifact

I know i probably put together different versions which don't work together but i don;t know how to figure out where. I'm new to maven and spring and this is a common problem i have so can you tell me what's wrong here and how to recognize on the future incompatible versions ?
Here is my pom.xml:

```
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>aopalliance</groupId>
        <artifactId>aopalliance</artifactId>
        <version>1.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.aspectj</groupId>
        <artifactId>aspectjweaver</artifactId>
        <version>1.8.6</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.gatein.common</groupId>
        <artifactId>common-logging</artifactId>
        <version>2.2.2.Final</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-aop</artifactId>
        <version>4.2.0.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-asm</artifactId>
        <version>3.1.4.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>servletapi</groupId>
        <artifactId>servlet-api</artifactId>
        <version>2.4-20040521</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-beans</artifactId>
        <version>4.2.0.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-context</artifactId>
        <version>4.2.0.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-core</artifactId>
        <version>4.2.0.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-expression</artifactId>
        <version>4.2.0.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-jdbc</artifactId>
        <version>1.2.6</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-security-config</artifactId>
        <version>4.0.2.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-security-core</artifactId>
        <version>4.0.2.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-security-web</artifactId>
        <version>4.0.2.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-web</artifactId>
        <version>4.2.0.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-webmvc</artifactId>
        <version>4.2.0.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-tx</artifactId>
        <version>4.2.0.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

I follow different tutorials while creating projects and because they are older I always face the dependency problem
http://www.studytrails.com/frameworks/spring/spring-security-using-xml.jsp

Comment: Which IDE are you using?

Comment: I hope I interpreted you answer correctly

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First try to create the property values as such (in pom.xml):

```
<properties>
    <spring.version>4.2.0.RELEASE</spring.version>
</properties>
<!-- both properties as dependencies are directly under `project`!, don't use 
`dependencyManagement` until later -->
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-beans</artifactId>
        <version>${spring.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-aop</artifactId>
        <version>${spring.version}</version>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

which makes it easier to update all at the same time.
To see whether different dependencies are used, open the pom.xml (in Eclipse)
Click on the `Dependency Hierarchy` tab (bottom)
Here you can see whether there are `conflicts` between dependencies, and how they are related with your code and the hierarchy of directly or indirectly imported dependencies.

Also what helps, is to check whether you've imported the last versions, by calling (see https://stackoverflow.com/a/2687228/928952 for an example)

```
mvn versions:display-dependency-updates
```

One more thing, wrt versions (see [version update policy](https://docs.oracle.com/middleware/1212/core/MAVEN/maven_version.htm#MAVEN8855)):

> 7.1 How Version Numbers Work in Maven Maven's versioning scheme uses the following standards:
>
> MajorVersion
>   MinorVersion
>   IncrementalVersion
>   BuildNumber
>   Qualifier For
>
> example:
>
> MajorVersion: 1.2.1
>   MinorVersion: 2.0
>   IncrementalVersion: 1.2-SNAPSHOT
>   BuildNumber: 1.4.2-12
>   Qualifier: 1.2-beta-2

Comment: ok. the property thing seems a good practice but i changed it in the spring-asm dependency and tells me it can't find the 4.2.0 version for it. And i'm not sure i understand the hierarchies i see there

Comment: Be aware, not all the Spring versions are updated equally, like Security is always (around) a full version behind, Asm (see http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework/spring-asm) also appears to be `3.1.4.RELEASE` as the latest... If you have a problem like the one you have now, check `http://mvnrepository.com/` and search for the dependency. There you'll find the last version

Comment: The `Dependency Hierarchy` can be somewhat overwhelming, especially when using `spring-framework` because it uses a lot of external sources. What you are especially looking for (I think), is when you see (in the left screen in particular) `[version conflict, omitting version]' (something like that)