# Check for Updated Version of Maven

Tags: java, maven, version, versioning

Is there a Maven plugin that allows you to check if there is a newer version of Maven itself?

Say, you are using Maven 3.3.3 and now a new version of Maven 3.3.9 is released.  I'd like to know that there is a new version available.

The question [Maven check for updated dependencies in repository](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2687220/maven-check-for-updated-dependencies-in-repository) deals with showing any dependency updates.  That is not this question.  However, please see the comments for this question of how an answer in [Maven check for updated dependencies in repository](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2687220/maven-check-for-updated-dependencies-in-repository) solves the problem.

Comment: Actually, that question does answer this. You just need to check the `maven-plugin-api` dependency which is released for every Maven release. There is a 1-1 correlation between `maven-plugin-api` and releases of Maven.

Comment: @Tunaki none of the answers in the linked question make that clear.  I would have never guessed that.  Can you turn your comment into an answer for this question?

Comment: Well it will just repeat the linked answer. It is better to leave this as a duplicate.

Comment: I also think this is not really a duplicate, your comment/answer was not easy to guess from the linked question.

Comment: What about [checking Maven Central via REST API](http://search.maven.org/#api) ? Or [subscribe to the announcement mail list](http://maven.apache.org/mail-lists.html)..