# How to check for updates on Android Gradle dependencies using CLI commands?

Tags: android, maven, android-studio, gradle, command-line

## TL; DR

Just like Maven command [`mvn versions:display-dependency-updates`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2687220), is it possible check for Gradle dependencies updates using command line interface?

## Details

A good practice of how to organize Android projects is [add extra configurations for versioning dependencies](https://medium.com/google-developer-experts/19-tips-for-gradle-in-android-projects-2019-edition-11af704eb06e). A shard of [`dependencies.gradle`](https://github.com/hitherejoe/GithubTrending) such file would look like:

```
ext {
    rxAndroid = '2.0.0',
    timber    = '4.5.0'

    mobileUiDependencies = [
        rxAndroid : "io.reactivex.rxjava2:rxandroid:${versions.rxAndroid}",
        timber    : "com.jakewharton.timber:timber:${timberVersion}",
    ]
}
```

However such modifications messes with [Android Studio inspector](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28683327), **incorrectly** showing that **no dependency updates are available**:

[image: Newer Library Versions Available]

Would it be possible:

1. Fix Android Studio new dependencies inspector behavior?
2. Run a inspector using Gradle command line?

The CLI not only solves it, but also script allows to create a dependencies auto-bumper script (like [Node.js Greenkeeper](https://greenkeeper.io/)).

## References

1. [Stack Overflow: Maven check for update dependencies in repository](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2687220)
2. [Medium GDE: 19 Tips for Gradle in Android Projects](https://medium.com/google-developer-experts/19-tips-for-gradle-in-android-projects-2019-edition-11af704eb06e)
3. [Caster I/O: Android Clean Arch - GitHub Trendings project](https://github.com/hitherejoe/GithubTrending)
4. [Stack Overflow: How to check if Gradle dependency has new version](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28683327)
5. [Node.js Greenkeeper](https://greenkeeper.io/)