# Download latest Junit for Maven

Tags: maven, repository, nexus

I have Maven and Nexus configured in my project and now I need to get the latest version of JUnit into my Nexus.

If I search Nexus, it shows the latest version available on Maven Central, but how do I download it ?

I don't even know in which repository the existing JUnit lies. I have about 15 repositories in Nexus and I'm not able to really find it.

So, in short:

1. Where do I find my existing JUnit version in Nexus local and how?
2. When I do find it and want to upgrade to latest, how to do it?

Comment: for 2., see [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/3256686/250517)

Answer (score 1):

1. Just use the search feature. For that to work nicely you will have to have remote index download configured. Once you found it the results will show in which repository it is.
2. What JUnit version you use will depend on the dependency declared in your build system. E.g. if you use Maven it might look like this

```xml
<dependency>
    <groupId>junit</groupId>
    <artifactId>junit-dep</artifactId>
    <version>4.11</version>
    <scope>test</scope>
</dependency>
```

In general I would suggest to read up on Nexus usage and repository manager basics in the free book [Repository Management with Nexus](http://www.sonatype.com/Support/Books/Repository-Management-with-Nexus) and maybe on your build system as well. If it is Maven a good start are the Maven books at http://www.sonatype.com/Support/Books .

**Disclaimer:** I am co-author of the Nexus book.