# always update maven dependencies with MAVEN_OPTS

Tags: maven

Have found that almost always need to specify -U in maven commands.  Is there a way to do this with the MAVEN_OPTS environment variable?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Maven automatic SNAPSHOT update](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2358965/maven-automatic-snapshot-update)

Comment: check the linked post, you are most probably looking for the `always` for `updatePolicy`

Comment: The -U options is primarily for SNAPSHOT versions. This can be better handled with the update policy as @A_Di-Matteo already mentioned.

Comment: -U is also for missing release versions, which is the case I am interested in

Answer (score 0):

You can configure your local settings (usually in ~/.m2/settings.xml) following the reference page in http://maven.apache.org/ref/3.3.9/maven-settings/settings.html

The option to be set is *updatePolicy*

> updatePolicy: The frequency for downloading updates - can be "always", "daily" (default), "interval:XXX" (in minutes) or "never" (only if it doesn't exist locally).