# How to enable inside glassfish access to maven repository?

Tags: maven, glassfish

I have a following problem. We have a central maven repository hosted on our company server. Our team is working on a project. Everyone here uses that repository to get the required artifacts. If something is missing at the moment and is required for the task that the developer is currently dealing with, he installs this artifact manually to the central repository, so that his commits don't break the automated builds.

Now, each developer also has Glassfish v2 installed on his machine. That is for testing and debugging purposes. Before committing the changes, developer makes the .ear for the project with Maven help. However, after the developer deploys the ear to it's local glassfish, frequent errors arise, because the set of glassfish libraries may not contain all the latest dependencies of the central company repository.

Right now in case of the error the developer simply reads the log and looks what exactly is missing. After that he manually copies the required jar inside his local $GLASSFISH_HOME$/lib dir. But that seems a little bit frustrating. How can this be done automatically?

Right now we are trying to implement the following solution. The developer has to synchronize his local maven repository gathering all the artifacts from the central one that are required by the project. This local repository has to be placed on the java classpath, so that glassfish would also see it. Is that a correct approach? Maybe there is a way to install directly all the required artifacts from the central repository inside $GLASSFISH_HOME$/dir and this can be done automatically during deploy?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- About having to install dependencies. If the developers need to install dependencies missing from public maven repositories, take into account that usually maven proxies have the ability to cache public repos. For instance, [archiva has a proxying cache](http://archiva.apache.org/docs/1.3.5/tour/proxy.html). If the dependencies are your own project deliverables you should consider [releasing and deploying with maven](http://maven.apache.org/guides/mini/guide-releasing.html) to your company repo.
- About latest versions. You need to specify maven what version of dependencies should use. I would prefer editing my poms manually, anyway there's a [variety of ways to achieve that](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30571/how-do-i-tell-maven-to-use-the-latest-version-of-a-dependency).
- The libraries should be part of the project, I think. If not standard libraries of glassfish, they should be included, for instance, in your war file as part of your project. If not standard but not part of your project (not the regular approach) consider managing this glassfish as a project on its own (own git/svn repo, own pom, own versions, own everything).

Good luck.