# import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestController cannot be resolved

Tags: spring, spring-mvc

I'm using Eclipse Kepler..I tried to use 
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestController
But this import statement is not getting resolved
I've added all the dependencies required for that..but restcontroller is not getting resolved..

```
package s;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMethod;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.ResponseBody;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestController;
@RestController
public class RestController {



@Autowired Bean bean;
@RequestMapping(value="/springAngularJS", method=RequestMethod.GET)

public @ResponseBody Bean getBean() {      
Bean bean=new Bean();
    bean.setUserName("savitha");

    bean.setAge("22");

    bean.setCompany("Infosys");

    bean.setDesignation("ApplicationDeveloper");

    return bean;
  }
  }
```

And my pom.xml is

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"        xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
```

xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0
    http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">

```
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
<groupId>AngularRest</groupId>
<artifactId>AngularRest</artifactId>
<packaging>war</packaging>
<version>1.0</version>
<name>AngularRest</name>
<url>http://maven.apache.org</url>
<properties>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
</properties>

<repositories>
    <repository>
        <id>objectdb</id>
        <name>ObjectDB Repository</name>
        <url>http://m2.objectdb.com</url>
    </repository>
</repositories>

<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>slf4j-api</artifactId>
        <version>1.7.5</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>slf4j-simple</artifactId>
        <version>1.6.4</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>slf4j-log4j12</artifactId>
        <version>1.7.5</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.objectdb</groupId>
        <artifactId>objectdb</artifactId>
        <version>2.0.4</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
        <artifactId>servlet-api</artifactId>
        <version>2.5</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.servlet.jsp</groupId>
        <artifactId>jsp-api</artifactId>
        <version>2.1</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-webmvc</artifactId>
        <version>3.0.5.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-tx</artifactId>
        <version>3.0.5.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-orm</artifactId>
        <version>3.0.5.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>aopalliance</groupId>
        <artifactId>aopalliance</artifactId>
        <version>1.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>cglib</groupId>
        <artifactId>cglib</artifactId>
        <version>2.2</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.aspectj</groupId>
        <artifactId>aspectjweaver</artifactId>
        <version>1.6.10</version>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>

<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.3.2</version>
            <configuration>
                <source>1.5</source>
                <target>1.5</target>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.mortbay.jetty</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-jetty-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>6.1.10</version>
            <configuration>
                <scanIntervalSeconds>10</scanIntervalSeconds>
                <stopKey>foo</stopKey>
                <stopPort>9999</stopPort>
            </configuration>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <id>start-jetty</id>
                    <phase>pre-integration-test</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>run</goal>
                    </goals>
                    <configuration>
                        <scanIntervalSeconds>0</scanIntervalSeconds>
                        <daemon>true</daemon>
                    </configuration>
                </execution>
                <execution>
                    <id>stop-jetty</id>
                    <phase>post-integration-test</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>stop</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
    <finalName>AngularRest</finalName>
</build>
```

Thanks in advance..

Comment: Please share pom.xml or jar list of your project, if you have pom it will be good to share your pom dependency graph.

Comment: I had the same issue. I already had a spring-web dependency, on removing that and adding spring-boot dependencies the problem was solved.

Answer (score 35):

The problem is your class is named "RestController" and that conflicts with the actual RestController class used for the annotation. You just need to rename your class/file to something else like "DemoController" to avoid the class name conflict or specify the full path like @org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestController so it knows which one to use

Comment: Works for me! Thanks =]

Comment: Super!!, Thanks.

Answer (score 21):

I had the same issue i found the solution [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8422720/what-dependency-is-missing-for-org-springframework-web-bind-annotation-requestma).
Add this dependency to the pom.xml

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-web</artifactId>
        <version>4.1.6.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
```

Answer (score 7):

@RestController annotation since spring-web 4.0

Answer (score 2):

Sometimes .jar files does not get downloaded via Maven properly. Please perform maven update on the project.

Answer (score 1):

for a simple boot application,just check these dependencies in your pom.xml:

```
   <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>com.example</groupId>
    <artifactId>bootbtb</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>jar</packaging>

    <name>bootbtb</name>
    <description>bus project for Spring Boot</description>

    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>1.5.9.RELEASE</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>

    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <project.reporting.outputEncoding>UTF-8</project.reporting.outputEncoding>
        <java.version>1.8</java.version>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
    <dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-web</artifactId>
    <version>4.1.6.RELEASE</version>
</dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
         <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-webmvc</artifactId>
        <version>4.1.6.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>

</dependencies>


    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>


</project>
```

Answer (score 1):

I was having similar problem using springboot, my spring version in Pom was

```
<artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
<version>2.0.1.RELEASE</version>
```

I changed the version to 
`<version>1.5.9.RELEASE</version>`

clean  the project after that and import, that would work.

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you change spring mvc version?

I had experienced the same problem using springboot.
In my case the problem is version. 
So I had change version 1.2.3 -> 1.2.2.
Then the problem was solved.

Answer (score 0):

update properties in pom.xml as

```
<properties>
    <spring.version>4.0.0.RELEASE</spring.version>
   </properties>
```