# How to check the lastest dependency on Maven

Tags: maven, maven-2, maven-3

Is there any method to check whether a dependency is latest or not? I am wonder any web site can provide such functionality.

Comment: What do you mean by the latest? Do you mean if the dependency version is newest ? Such thing ?

Comment: SO as an excellent thread on this subject : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30571/how-do-i-tell-maven-to-use-the-latest-version-of-a-dependency

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can find out the latest version of any maven dependency deployed on Maven Central through [search.maven.org](http://search.maven.org)

If you are finding any dynamic ways of doing it, I do not know of any except for using [aether](http://www.sonatype.org/aether) library provided by Sonatype which can allow you to find out the latest version of a particular library deployed in any repository.

Maven does allow specifying version ranges in the dependency but it goes against philosophy of reproducible builds. I have read on the Maven users list that people discourage this practice.

Answer (score 1):

If you're trying to find updates to dependencies you've declared in your pom, the [maven versions plugin](http://mojo.codehaus.org/versions-maven-plugin/) works pretty well:

```
mvn versions:display-dependency-updates
mvn versions:display-plugin-updates
```