# Maven: determine if newer versions of libraries are used by dependencies vs. the project

Tags: maven, versioning, maven-3

I have several sets of libraries.  For example:

- Core 1.0
- Core 1.5
- Web 1.0 (uses Core 1.0)
- Drawing 1.0 (uses Core 1.5)

My problem arises when I have a project that uses both the Web and Drawing libraries.  I hard-code the version number of the Core library in a dependencyManagement section of my project, and update it from time to time.  I want to make sure that if a newer version of Core is used by Web or Drawing, that I update the version number in dependencyManagement.

versions:display-dependency-updates tells me if there are any new versions of Core available, but I don't want to update to a newer version unless Web or Drawing requires it.

Is there a way to determine if dependencies require newer versions of other dependencies than my project is using?

Thanks.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30571/how-do-i-tell-maven-to-use-the-latest-version-of-a-dependency

Or

mvn versions:use-latest-versions

Comment: I don't want to upgrade to the latest version of a transitive dependency if the dependency doesn't use the latest version.  I want highest version being actively used.

Comment: maven automatically does this when resolving dependencies - you can look in the dependency-tree output to see which are 'version managed' up to the newer version

Answer (score 1):

You can use `mvn -Dverbose dependency:tree` to see dependency hierarchy and it will also show you version conflicts like you've described.

Also can use `mvn versions:display-dependency-updates` to see updated dependencies.

Comment: That's a good idea and helps.  My project is big so the list is several pages long; is there a way to just list conflicts somehow?

Comment: I suppose you can grep it. :)  Though there is also versions:display-dependency-updates

Comment: For example: mvn -Dverbose dependency:tree | grep "conflict"