# Downloading latest jar files

Tags: java, maven, jar

I have a list of jar files. I want to check whether any new version is available.  One way to do so is to check one by one. I was wondering if there is a another shorter way of doing it?

Comment: I see you have maven in your tags - maven is great for this kind of thing, but are you saying that it's still not enough?

Comment: maybe related? http://stackoverflow.com/a/1172371

Comment: *"I have a list of Jar files"*  What are they used for?  E.G. A web-app., a desktop app., ..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If this question is really Maven related, this can be achieved by using the [versions-maven-plugin](http://mojo.codehaus.org/versions-maven-plugin/examples/display-dependency-updates.html).
Go into your project an do the following on command line:

```
mvn versions:display-dependency-updates
```

Answer (score 1):

check out [IVY](http://ant.apache.org/ivy/)

Apache Ivy brings the dependency management advantages of Apache Maven™ to Apache Ant build files

Answer (score 0):

For maven, use maven-versions-plugin to find out if new version of dependencies is available.

```
mvn versions:display-dependency-updates
```