# Managing Java Plugins in the Enterprise

Tags: java, plugins

I have many projects in my company and every project has its own set of java plugins and versions. Is there a way I better manage the plugins for all my applications to ensure they are all up to date?

The concept is similar to a patch management system, where it stores information about the patch levels for all your servers, and you have a way to uniformly apply the patch across all your machines.

I would like to establish a similar infrastructure for our development environment. Is there a way at all?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could try using maven as a build system for your projects and set up a central nexus/artifactory server where you set all the needed dependencies.

In your pom.xml you can define which major/minor version you would like to use. (as answered here: [How do I tell Maven to use the latest version of a dependency?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30571/how-do-i-tell-maven-to-use-the-latest-version-of-a-dependency))