# Need help on automating QA, Stage, Prod delpoy using Jenkins\Hudson

Tags: jenkins, hudson

We are using Hudson as a CI tool. At present we are needed to use Jenkins, to deploy the build to Stage, Prod environment. What is the best aproach we should follow.

I know about promote buld plugin, but the issue is authentication. I want whevener we need to promote a build to deploy to Stage or Prod, it should ask for netqwork credential first. And then the promote job should execute the Batch command using the creadential supplied. At present, the promote plugin, runs using the credentials which the Tomcat server is configured to run.

Same issue with Build Pipeline plugin.

I want only dev or even hudson admin also should not be able to execute the promote build unless credential supplied. (We have windows 2008 r2 OS)

Can you please help me in resolving the issue. so that basically whenever a user click on Promote build to QA\Stage\Prod the plugin should ask for credential or should use the logged on users credential and execute the batch script using the logged users credential only and not by using the credentials of the account with which the tomcat server is configured.

Can you please help me?

Please suggests us the best aproach for making automated build on prod\stage.

Answer (score 0):

For deployment I normally use SSH, Private/Public keys takes care of the authentication problems normally associated with running commands on other servers.

SSH is normally associated with unix based systems, but it does support windows.

Finally, I would recommend considering decoupling your build system (jenkins) from the system performing the deployment by using an intermediate repository. See the following answer for more details:

- [Jenkins : how to check out artifact from Nexus and Deploy on Tomcat-](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11848406/jenkins-how-to-check-out-artifact-from-nexus-and-deploy-on-tomcat/11852506#11852506)