# Best way to manage dependent ant builds over multiple servers?

Tags: ant, build, continuous-integration, distributed

I have these ant scripts that build and deploy my appservers.  My system though is actually over 3 servers.  They all use the same deploy script (w/flags) and all work fine.

Problem is there are some dependencies.  They all use the same database so I need a way to stop all appservers across all machines before the build first happens on machine 1.  Then I need the deployment on machine 1 to go and complete first as it's the one that deals with the database build (which all appservers need to start).

I've had a search around and there are some tools that might be useful but they all seem overkill for what I need.

What do you think would be the best tool to sync and manage the ant builds over multiple machines (all running linux)?

Thanks,
Ryuzaki

Comment: See: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11848406/jenkins-how-to-check-out-artifact-from-nexus-and-deploy-on-tomcat/11852506#11852506

Answer (score 1):

You could make your database changes non-breaking, run your database change scripts first and then deploy to your appservers. This way your code changes aren't intrinsically tied to your database changes and both can happen independently.

When I say non-breaking I mean that database changes are written in such a way that 2 different version of code can function against the same database. For example rather than renaming columns, you add a new one instead.

Comment: is on to something... It may be well worth your while to examine how the apps use the DB. The deployment woes you mentioned are a symptom of that problem.  You likely can mitigate your problems in build/deployment - but there isn't a solution there.

Comment: Not really got control over that sadly.  The product's database behaviour is outwith my remit.  Thanks though!

Comment: What I'm looking for is a manager for ant scripts across multiple machines I guess.