# Downloading nexus artifacts

Tags: jenkins, ant, jenkins-plugins, nexus

I am using ANT to build artifacts(finally all artifacts will be zipped in one zip file) and jenkins plugin 'Nexus Artifact Uploader' to upload artifact to nexus repository.

I want to download the artifact(zip file) from nexus repository using ANT OR jenkins plugin only. I am not supposed to use maven for this task. Also, unix commands like 'wget' or 'curl' are not allowed in my deployment environment. It fails with permission denied error. So, I want solution using either ANT or jenkins plugin only.

Can anyone please help.

Comment: try to check this thread - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11848406/jenkins-how-to-check-out-artifact-from-nexus-and-deploy-on-tomcat

Comment: I am sorry, I forgot to mention that unix commands like 'wget' or 'curl' are not allowed in my deployment environment. It fails with permission denied error. So, I want solution using either ANT or jenkins plugin.

Comment: are you using jenkins pipelines or old fashion jenkins jobs ?

Comment: I am using old fashion jenkins job as it is not that complex project. I have a job to build and upload artifacts to nexus. And this second job will download these artifacts and upload to target runtime. But there is almost no possibility of executing deployment job after completing build job. Deployment job will be executed less frequently compared to build job. So there won't be any pipeline here.

Comment: I see, if you can use jenkins2.0 Jenkinsfiles (aka pipelines) it will give you possibility to download from nexus via clean Groovy code, which will make your life easier.

Comment: Can you use external ant tasks?  https://maven.apache.org/resolver-archives/resolver-ant-tasks-LATEST/index.html

Comment: @rseddon I am already using ant contrib tasks. But I think I have to configure Maven for the tasks you mentioned in your comment. Deployment environment will ONLY have Apache Ant, Java and Jenkins.Nothing else is allowed to be installed/configured there.

Comment: Apache Ant Get task looks promising... I tried to implement it as below:

Comment: Apache Ant -> Get task looks promising... I tried to implement it as below: '<get src="http://localhost:8789/redirect?r=maven-releases&amp;g=com.example&amp;a=test&amp;v=39&amp;e=zip" dest="@{dest}" username="admin" password="admin123" verbose="true" />'.. but it throws FileNotFound Exception. Can anyone please help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use below ant project snippet to download artifacts from nexus

```
<project name="testdown" default="dependencies" basedir=".">
 <target name="dependencies">
<mkdir dir="libraries" />
<get src="http://10.135.155.72:8081/repository/maven-central/log4j/log4j/1.2.9/log4j-1.2.9.jar" dest="liblibraries/log4j-1.2.9.jar" usetimestamp="true" />
</target>
</project>
```

Comment: Can you please let me know how can I upload the artifact to nexus using ANT. Right now I am using Jenkins plugin.

Comment: you can use nexus artifact uploader plug in available for jenkins.
https://wiki.jenkins.io/display/JENKINS/Nexus+Artifact+Uploader

Comment: I am already using this plugin. In our project, jenkins admin is a very busy person :P. So, I don't want to wait for his availability. My ant script should upload artifact i.e. zip file to nexus repository.