# annotation before is missing value for the attribute value

Tags: java, netbeans, junit

I normally don't experience problem with JUnit annotation. But somehow today, with my new install of Netbeans 7.2, I am experiencing the following error when I use the `@Before` annotation:

```
annotation before is missing value for the attribute value
```

Does anyone know how to fix this?

---

UPDATE

I am writing a mavenized web-app.
For the TestCase, when I try to import `org.junit.Before` the program instead imports `org.aspectj.lang.annotation.Before`

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Are you declarig a dependency to an up to date JUnit Version?

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>junit</groupId>
    <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
    <version>4.10</version>
    <scope>test</scope>
</dependency>
```

You should be able to import the right class: `org.junit.Before`.

Comment: I am very new to Maven. Is there a way to tell Maven to get the latest version of all dependencies by default?

Comment: kasavbere, although I deeply recommend you to use concrete library versions - so that new library updates do not break the build, or even worse, introduce subtle bugs at runtime - there are some approaches to do what you want. Refer to his post for further info: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30571/how-do-i-tell-maven-to-use-the-latest-version-of-a-dependency.

Answer (score 12):

Are you still getting the same error even after adding junit dependency in `pom.xml`?

Check to see that you are importing the right library i.e.

```
import org.junit.Before;
```

instead of

```
import org.aspectj.lang.annotation.Before;
```

Answer (score 1):

This is a pretty old question but for anyone tripping over this error in 2023 after switching to the new `JUnit Jupiter` or using the latest `spring-boot-dependencies`  bom file (which automatically configures you for `Jupiter` unless you override it):

Note that as of `Jupiter`, the [org.junit.Before](https://junit.org/junit4/javadoc/latest/org/junit/Before.html) annotation was replaced with the [org.junit.jupiter.api.BeforeAll](https://javadoc.io/doc/org.junit.jupiter/junit-jupiter-api/latest/org/junit/jupiter/api/BeforeAll.html) annotation.

Some helpful URL references for the API changes:

- [Nice rundown of API changes from Junit4 to Jupiter](https://sormuras.github.io/blog/2018-09-13-junit-4-core-vs-jupiter-api.html)
- [Javadoc for Junit Jupiter](https://javadoc.io/doc/org.junit.jupiter/junit-jupiter-api/latest/index.html)