# How to make maven use the latest release version within version range?

Tags: maven, maven-2

In my maven project I use dependencies like this:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.httpcomponents</groupId>
    <artifactId>httpclient</artifactId>
    <version>[4.2.2, 5.0)</version>
</dependency>
```

Since the next major version (5.0) may change the API, I want my project to use the latest **stable** version available for branch 4.x.

This morning bug investigation told me this expression [4.2.2, 5.0) grabs **any** version available. In my case: 4.3-alpha1.

How to make maven use thelatest release version within version range?

Comment: There is a similar page here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30571/how-do-i-tell-maven-to-use-the-latest-version-of-a-dependency

Comment: @Gavin there is no answer to my question at the link. I have seen it before prior to question.

Comment: I assume you use maven2 (given the question tags). Maven strongly discourage this, as this can lead to non reproductible build. AND this will make any future migration to recent maven version a painful process. So, I strongly discourage this, as useful as it may seem.

Comment: @SamuelEUSTACHI Now I've got the point. Thank you.

Comment: You're welcome. I had the same idea, about dependencies between my own projects. I would assume that the risk is not as big as for a dependency from an external provider. But I discovered that this is not a good practice, even in this case. For instance, the pom of a version of your pom can also serve a some kind of "self-documentation" for your project, and then it is useful to be able to know exactly the set of libraries used at compile time and runtime. You might want to know this for later debugging.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Looking at the documentation for [Maven range selections](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVENOLD/Dependency+Mediation+and+Conflict+Resolution), I notice the comment:

> Resolution of dependency ranges should not resolve to a snapshot (development version) unless it is included as an explicit boundary.

Unless the artifact version ends with `-SNAPSHOT`, Maven is going to consider it a valid release build. As far as I know, `-alpha1` has no special meaning to Maven. It's just another random qualifier.

I would strongly recommend you forgo the version range, anyway. Predictable builds should be the goal of any stable project and version ranges fly in the face of that.

Comment: Thank you for the advice about ranges. Starting with Maven, it's not always clear which option to take.

Comment: The linked documentation is a design draft for Maven 2.0. The final implementation actually slightly differ.

Comment: `Predictable builds should be the goal of any stable project and version ranges fly in the face of that.` Unless you care about security more than predictable builds. If a build is broken, everyone sees it and hurries to fix. If a vulnerability is found, no one cares.

Comment: "It should not" but it will according to this issue: https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/MNG-3092

Comment: I use maven 3.5.3, which does opposite to the doc by considering snapshot as a valid version.

Answer (score 1):

Maven 3 supports versioning for alpha, beta and snapshots as well
with the following order 

`alpha < beta < snapshot`

Comment: Any source for that?

Comment: The source code is explicit: https://github.com/apache/maven/blob/maven-3.3.9/maven-artifact/src/main/java/org/apache/maven/artifact/versioning/ComparableVersion.java#L149 (see the method `ComparableVersion.StringItem.comparableQualifier(String)`).

And the Javadoc states that: << strings are checked for well-known qualifiers and the qualifier ordering is used for version ordering. Well-known qualifiers (case insensitive) are: alpha or a, beta or b, milestone or m, rc or cr, snapshot, (the empty string) or ga or final, sp >>

Comment: As @JulienCarsique, already replied source is https://github.com/apache/maven/blob/maven-3.3.9/maven-artifact/src/main/java/org/apache/maven/artifact/versioning/ComparableVersion.java#L149

Comment: And also in the documentation: https://maven.apache.org/pom.html you find the following: `"alpha" < "beta" < "milestone" < "rc" = "cr" < "snapshot" < "" = "final" = "ga" < "sp"`