# How to set Maven version range exclusive of alpha, beta and snapshot of ending condition?

Tags: java, maven, version

For example, I have this maven dependency

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>foo</groupId>
    <artefactId>bar</artifactId>
    <version>[1.0.0, 1.1.0)</version>
</dependency>
```

The goal I'm trying to achieve is to include all patch (1.0.x) releases, including SNAPSHOT releases (to facilitate testing and integration), like `1.0.1-SNAPSHOT`, `1.0.2` etc.

However, setting a version range like this `[1.0.0, 1.1.0)` will include versions like `1.1.0-alpha`, `1.1.0-beta` and `1.1.0-SNAPSHOT` as well, which is something I don't want.

Is there a better way, short of specifying the version as `[1.0.0, 1.1.0-alpha)`, which really just pollutes the POM with ugly versions numbers.

(It is not about trying to use the latest version, but about how to gracefully exclude `alpha`, `beta` and `snapshot` builds in an exclusive version range)

Comment: Possible duplicate is here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14432039/how-to-make-maven-use-the-latest-release-version-within-version-range

Comment: It's not a duplicate. That question is about using the latest version available. My question is about exclusive version range should not include `alpha`, 'beta` and `snapshot` builds