# Sonatype Nexus OSS using LATEST in pom.xml gives unresolved dependency (maven2)

Tags: maven, version, pom.xml, nexus, sonatype

I have a Sonatype Nexus OSS install, and I have artifacts on it. However, when using "LATEST" for the version in the pom.xml, I get an unresolved dependency error. Is there something I have to enable to allow the LATEST keyword? I've looked everywhere

Comment: What's the Pom.xml look like - i.e., where you are using that keyword?  Might help to see it.  If you haven't already, You might look at comments here:  http://stackoverflow.com/a/1172371/652078

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Maven client does not true support dynamic revisions. The closest thing it supports are snapshot revisions, where a revision like 1.0-SNAPSHOT, is resolved to the latest time-stamped artifact.

I think you may be confusing the Maven POM with the [REST API](https://repository.sonatype.org/nexus-restlet1x-plugin/default/docs/index.html) used by Nexus. This the ability to specify a "LATEST" version:

- https://repository.sonatype.org/service/local/artifact/maven/redirect?r=central-proxy&g=log4j&a=log4j&v=LATEST&e=jar