# External resources in a java/maven project suddenly invalid?

Tags: java, maven, import

I have a project that I came back to a couple months since last working on and noticed the majority of the external classes I've been importing and using in my project are now invalid and unable to be found. Pic attached [image]

And when I run maven clean install, I get errors along the lines of

```
java:[141,17] reference to JsonNode is ambiguous, both class org.codehaus.jackson.JsonNode in org.codehaus.jackson and class com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonNode in com.fasterxml.jackson.databind match
```

There are several errors of this kind, referencing the line numbers that use the classes unable to be imported.

Could these issues be related? If so what's a simple way to just to reinstall the libraries I need to use in the project and get rid of the collisions?

Thanks for any help,
-Adam

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you didn't change anything in the project, the maven build probably picked up a newer version of some dependency in your pom.xml. You probably have some dependencies on the latest release or on version ranges for some artifacts, as described in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30571/how-do-i-tell-maven-to-use-the-latest-version-of-a-dependency).

My guess is that the dependency on jackson-databind has changed from 2.2.x to 2.3.0, which was released to the maven central repository quite recently ([see here](http://search.maven.org/#search%7Cgav%7C1%7Cg%3A%22com.fasterxml.jackson.core%22%20AND%20a%3A%22jackson-databind%22)). Between 2.2.x and 2.3.0, they moved the class `JsonNode` into the package `com.fasterxml.jackson.databind`

If this is the cause of the problem, the build will be more repeatable and consistent if you set specific version dependencies, or at least narrower ranges, in the pom. In the case of jackson-databind, try setting the version to 2.2.3

Answer (score 0):

Check your classes that the compile error is referring to.  You probably have some imports like:

```
import org.codehaus.jackson.*;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.*;
```

Then later you are trying to use a JsonNode.  The compiler is telling you that's "ambiguous" because both of the above imports have a class named "JsonNode".  You just need to call out which JsonNode you want by specifying it with the full classpath in your code.

```
org.codehaus.jackson.JsonNode node = new org.codehaus.jackson.JsonNode();
```

(Or something like that)

Once your maven build finishes, those other errors will probably go away in your IDE Screenshot.

Comment: Ok but is there any other cleaner solution without having to specify the class path each time I use one of those classes? Because I know when I first wrote all my code, none of this was an issue, then for some reason all of a sudden there were these errors when I looked at the project again.

Comment: It's also showing those red errors in the import statements for many different things, not just jackson related stuff from fasterxml or codehaus