# SBT complains about Maven's RELEASE as version of (transitive) dependencies?

Tags: maven, playframework-2.0, sbt, playframework-2.2

I'm trying to add `"com.google.api-ads" % "adwords-axis" % "1.23.0"` as a dependency in `build.sbt` file in a Play 2.2.1 project. When I do `play eclipse` for generating the eclipse project file, I get the following error:

```
[error] (*:update) sbt.ResolveException: unresolved dependency: com.google.http-client#google-http-client-jackson2;RELEASE: not found
```

Later I found out that [adwords-axis](https://github.com/googleads/googleads-java-lib/blob/1.23.0/modules/adwords_axis/pom.xml) depends on [ads-lib](https://github.com/googleads/googleads-java-lib/blob/1.23.0/modules/ads_lib/pom.xml) which has the following dependency (note `RELEASE` version):

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>com.google.http-client</groupId>
  <artifactId>google-http-client-jackson2</artifactId>
  <version>RELEASE</version>
</dependency>
```

I read that the version can be specified as `RELEASE` in Maven in this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1172371/434678).

Does SBT not allow specifying the version as `RELEASE`? If so, is there a workaround to use `adwords-axis` dependency?

Answer (score 0):

I don't think there is such functionality in SBT and it is probably also not a good idea since the API might change totally between two releases and your project would then download any new version making your build non-repeatable, if you check out an old version from your VCS its not certain that it will compile etc. So it is a pretty bad decision by the project maintainers of the library that uses RELEASE as the version of any dependency.

What you can do though is to figure out what version it would resolve to now, if it really works and then override the transitive dependency with that specific version of google-http-client-jackson2 and depend directly on that.

So for example (not that I'm just randomly guessing that 0.17.0-rc would be a good version):

```
libraryDependencies := Seq(
  "com.google.api-ads" % "adwords-axis" % "1.23.0",
  "com.google.http-client" % "google-http-client-jackson2" % "1.17.0-rc"
)
```

Comment: I have seen excluding transitive dependencies in maven. I'll try what you have suggested and get back. Thanks

Comment: There is also support for excluding transitive dependencies in a few ways in sbt, but I guessed that you will actually need the http-client.