# Named versions in Maven?

Tags: maven, maven-3, dependency-management

We are using mvn pom.xmls to specify interdependency between our various modules that make up the project.
The numeric version for every module is incremented by the build system automatically when the module is released.
However, in this case, this would necessitate notifying every team to update the version their module depends on to the version we just released.

Can Maven instead just work in a way that users of a library specify something like, "depend on the 'STABLE' version of this module", and then with every build it would figure out which actual version number that translates to?

Comment: What you call a stable version is in maven called a release like `1.0.0` or similar which does *not* contain `-SNAPSHOT`.

Comment: Okay, and how do I express 'latest version which doesn't contain "SNAPSHOT"'?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I tell Maven to use the latest version of a dependency?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30571/how-do-i-tell-maven-to-use-the-latest-version-of-a-dependency)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why don't you just depend on the major version, and release minor versions?

```
<version>[1.,)</version>
```

You can also use RELEASE

```
<version>RELEASE</version>
```

However I guess [that's not supported in Maven 3](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/Maven+3.x+Compatibility+Notes).

See more discussion about the same topic from [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30571/how-do-i-tell-maven-to-use-the-latest-version-of-a-dependency).