# How to include a maven module outside of the project context?

Tags: java, maven, svn, maven-module

I'd like to have a module in some kind of global project directory, so that I can include that module in all other projects that use that common code.

But how can I then tell a maven parent `pom` to include and compile this global shared module?
The following does not work:

```
svn/MyGlobalProject/project-commons/pom.xml           //should be shared among different projects
svn/MyProject/web-parent/trunk/pom.xml                //the parent pom used to build the application
svn/MyProject/web-parent/trunk/project-domain/pom.xml //submodule 1
svn/MyProject/web-parent/trunk/project-web/pom.xml    //submodule 2
```

parent pom.xml:

```
<project>
        <groupId>de.project</groupId>
    <artifactId>project-parent</artifactId>
    <packaging>pom</packaging>

    <modules>
        <module>project-domain</module>
        <module>project-web</module>
        <module>../project-commons</module> <!-- Error -->
    </modules>
</project>
```

`mvn package` results in:

```
Child module trunk\project-commons of trunk\pom.xml does not exist
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you run `mvn install` on that global project, it will be installed in your local repository. Your other projects can then reference it as a dependency:

```xml
<dependency>
  <groupId>whatever</groupId>
  <artifactId>project-commons</artifactId>
  <version>1.0</version>
</dependency>
```

The downside of this simplistic approach is that your other projects won't compile until you've checked-out `project-commons` and run `mvn install`.

A more advanced approach is to deploy a network-accessible repository (such as [Artifactory](http://www.jfrog.com/home/v_artifactory_opensource_overview) or Nexus) which you can deploy global artifacts to. Artifactory has a community edition which is free. You can then list this repository in your settings file and Maven will resolve artifacts that are uploaded to it.

Comment: I'm trying to use the submodule approach to exactly avoid having to mvn install the project into repo.

Comment: @membersound Why? That is *exactly the purpose* of `mvn install`. To try and avoid this is to fight the very essence of Maven. I would recommend the Artifactory approach myself - easy to install and lots of benefits.

Comment: Hm ok. Is there any way to automatically detect changes in the commons when I deploy my module project that has a dependency to commons?

Comment: @membersound You can use the special version number `LATEST` or `RELEASE` to always refer to the newest commons artifact (snapshot and non-snapshot respectively). But this is frowned upon in the Maven community because it can lead to build instability. See [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30571/how-do-i-tell-maven-to-use-the-latest-version-of-a-dependency) for more info.

Comment: What if we need `project-commons` as a module itself, which can be used under profiles? Basically, I have several profiles in my pom and need `project-commons` as part of couple of the profiles. @DuncanJones

Answer (score 0):

Using relative path to include some submodules is not a good practice...you will have a lot of problems.

Can not you just put the common project as a dependency of the parent module...

In this way you will have that "common project" in all the submodule that declare the parent project as a parent...

Why do you want to compile your "common" project every time you compile the parent pom?

Edited:

YOUR SVN:

```
svn/MyGlobalProject/project-commons/pom.xml           //should be shared among different projects
svn/MyProject/web-parent/trunk/pom.xml                //the parent pom used to build the    application
svn/MyProject/web-parent/trunk/project-domain/pom.xml //submodule 1
svn/MyProject/web-parent/trunk/project-web/pom.xml    //submodule 2
```

PARENT POM.XML:

```
<project>
    <groupId>de.project</groupId>
    <artifactId>project-parent</artifactId>
    <packaging>pom</packaging>

    <dependencies>
       <dependency>
      <groupId>de.project</groupId>
      <artifactId>project-commons</artifactId>
      <version>${common.project.version}</version>
       <dependency>
    <dependencies>

<modules>
    <module>project-domain</module>
    <module>project-web</module>
</modules>
```

Just like this...
in that way project-domain and project-web will inherit that dependency, and you will able to use it everywhere you want in submodules...

Than the use of dependency management could be a good improvements

Comment: Could you give an example of this architecture? It sounds like maybe it's the right approach. I do not necessairly want to compile my common project every time. But I at least want it to be resolved from workspace by maven, and not having to install it in the maven repo.

Comment: You can't declare a dependency until the artifact has been installed somewhere. Hence my answer. This answer just suggests an alternative way to incorporate that dependency into a lot of children, which might be a sensible approach.

Comment: @ivoruJavaBoy ok but this would me also require to having installed the commons dependency into local repo. Then I could as well directly add the dependency to each module that requires it.

Comment: Yes...but I can not seem to find it difficult to install common project individually...As @membersound asks.. you can use some free Continous integration tools (like apache Continuum) to re-build and re-deploy on you remote repository (artifcatory, nexus) the common project after every commits...in that way you will be sure to use always the last SNAPSHOT of common project