# How to have maven profile with modules from other project

Tags: java, maven, multi-module, maven-module

I have a ModuleA in ProjectA and ModuleB in ProjectB. There is a profile in ProjectB which needs both the modules to be built. How do we achieve this ?

Basically, I want something like this,

```
<profile>
    <id>test</id>
    <modules>
       <module>ModuleA</module>  <!-- this throws error -->
       <module>ModuleB</module>
    </modules>
</profile>
```

I have gone through this question([How to include a maven module outside of the project context?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23912078/how-to-include-a-maven-module-outside-of-the-project-context)), but the requirement here is to have a profile with both the modules and not add ModuleA as dependency in ProjectB

Comment: Read about maven multimodule projects

Comment: @soorapadman Went through the multimodule projects, used it and browsed about my requirement, but was not of much help.

Answer (score 0):

If you need a profile in both, you need a common parent pom. The parent pom is usually the pom where you declare the modules, so define the profile there.

Comment: I need profile only in ProjectB and thing is both the projects have their own and different parent poms already.