# how to get maven to update a specific version dependency

Tags: java, maven

i'm kinda new to maven after coming from a simple yet uncouth ant world.

```
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.foo.bar.EPT</groupId>
        <artifactId>EPTUtils</artifactId>
        <version>1.2.9-SNAPSHOT</version>
        <scope>compile</scope>
    </dependency>
```

I'm looking for a maven command to specifically update this version to `1.2.14-SNAPSHOT`.  I've tried

```
mvn -DallowSnapshots=true versions:use-latest-snapshots -Dincludes=com.foo.bar.*
```

but that didn't update what i had in my local repo.

Comment: Is this part of your own project? The 'automatic' way in such cases is to apply proper maven release management. http://maven.apache.org/maven-release/maven-release-plugin/

Answer (score 1):

Change

```
<version>1.2.9-SNAPSHOT</version>
```

to

```
<version>1.2.14-SNAPSHOT</version>
```

in the `pom.xml` of your Maven project. Then build the project.

```
mvn clean test package
```

Maven will download the dependency and store it in your local `~/.m2` repository.

**Edit:** Also see [How do I tell Maven to use the latest version of a dependency?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30571/how-do-i-tell-maven-to-use-the-latest-version-of-a-dependency) for more information about Maven and latest versions.

**Edit 2:** You can use the [Versions Maven Plugin](http://mojo.codehaus.org/versions-maven-plugin/) that as goals that can help you with that.

Comment: yes, is there a maven command to update the pom.xml and set the version?

Comment: i want to script the update of the version number.  xml is not easily edited by a script to update the version number.

Comment: i was thinking maven would allow me to say: mvn updateDependencyVersion -DartifactID=EPTUTils 1.2.14-SNAPSHOT

Comment: thanks, i see the edit. in my original question i was referencing the version plugin.  it didn't seem to work.