# What is Maven equivalent of gradle '+'?

Tags: maven, gradle, version

In gradle one can do

```
compile 'com.myGroupid:myArifiactId:0.0.1+'
```

where '+' means just take the latest version which can be 0.0.1.061114

is there a way to mimic the "+' in maven?

Comment: Isn't it what You're looking for: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30571/how-do-i-tell-maven-to-use-the-latest-version-of-a-dependency ?

Comment: thx. please add as an answer and I would accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In maven it can be done as mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30571/how-do-i-tell-maven-to-use-the-latest-version-of-a-dependency). [Here](http://maven.apache.org/enforcer/enforcer-rules/versionRanges.html) You can find general rules of fetching artifacts from maven repo when it comes to versions.