# How to retrieve the LATEST (also SNAPSHOT) version of a maven artifact using aether API?

Tags: java, maven-3, aether

I'm using eclipse.aether (version 1.0.0.v20140518) to programmatically fetch some maven artifacts from my repository. To do this I am using the following code:

```
Artifact artifact = new DefaultArtifact( artifactName );
ArtifactRequest artifactRequest = new ArtifactRequest().setArtifact( artifact );
repositorySystem.resolveArtifact(session, artifactRequest);
```

where artifactName is a String in the format "groupId:artifactId:version". When version is a fixed version (like in "org.myNamespace:myProject:1.0.0") everything works fine. Moreover I should be allowed also to replace the fixed version with "LATEST" (as in "org.myNamespace:myProject:LATEST") and in this case it should load the latest version of that artifact in my repository.

This also works but only partially, meaning that it never retrieves SNAPSHOTs artifacts, but only releases. This doesn't seem to be compliant with maven semantic as it is also described here [How do I tell Maven to use the latest version of a dependency?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30571/how-do-i-tell-maven-to-use-the-latest-version-of-a-dependency)

Am I doing something wrong? Is there a way to load the latest version of an artifact regardless if it is a release or a snapshot?

Comment: Just use `1.0.0-SNAPSHOT` instead of `LATEST`.

Comment: This doesn't work. What happens if somebody deploys a 1.1.0-SNAPSHOT?

Answer (score 1):

Using an open range (not LATEST) works with `resolveVersionRange`. For example:

```
VersionRangeRequest request = new VersionRangeRequest();
request.setArtifact(new DefaultArtifact("groupId", "artifactId", "jar", "(,]"));
VersionRangeResult result = repositorySystem.resolveVersionRange(session, request);
Version highestVersion = result.getHighestVersion();
```

Comment: What to do with this `highestVersion`?

Comment: It's about a year since I wrote that, but I reckon that highestVersion will give you the latest version of an artifact (regardless if it's a release or SNAPSHOT). So this is what the asker wanted.

Comment: Is possible to resolve artifact with version like `CD-001`, `CD-002`, `CD-003`?

Comment: I think that would work, yes. If you have artifacts like this, why not try it out?

Comment: Yes, it works, but I need to search using this version: `"(,]"`

Comment: Aha, I see. Well, that makes sense.