# Maven: multiple versions for provided dependency

Tags: java, maven, dependency-management

Hi i need to declare a provided dependency in maven which can be more versions.

For example it can be v1.3 or v1.4 or v1.5.

How can I declare/represent multiple versions in a single notation ?

Comment: What you want to solve ??

Comment: Use v1.3 and above
or you can write v1.*

Regards!

Comment: I am coding a Addon for Vaadin. Therefore i need the vaadin-server dependency in my project. but i don't want my addon to be bound on a particular version.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maven supports dependency range, this worked for me

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>junit</groupId>
        <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
        <version>[4.9,4.10]</version>
    </dependency>
```

it chooses highest available

Comment: Don't use version ranges.

Answer (score 0):

In maven you should always use version element for example:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.google.guava</groupId>
    <artifactId>guava</artifactId>
    <version>17.0</version>
</dependency>
```

If you want to use latest version of some plugin you should read this question answer [How do I tell Maven to use the latest version of a dependency?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30571/how-do-i-tell-maven-to-use-the-latest-version-of-a-dependency).

Answer (score 0):

Use **v1.3 and above**

or you can write ***v1.****

Regards!

Comment: I've just tried this but it didn't work for me, Evgeniy Dorofeev's solution did it for me...