# Specify highest/lowest version for maven dependency

Tags: java, maven, maven-3

Using the following versioning logic

## major.minor.build

is there any way to specify that my project depends on a **specific major** version, the **highest minor** and the **lowest build** number?

I need to do this because I'm using the **maven-dependency-plugin** to copy all the dependencies of our multiple WAR files into a common folder, so that it can be sent to the client the latest version, but at the same time keep the numbers of packages to a minimum.

Comment: Look here : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30571/how-do-i-tell-maven-to-use-the-latest-version-of-a-dependency

Comment: I had already looked into that, but that doesn't explain how to use the lowest available.

Comment: Take a deep look at the maven-assembly-plugin would be easier and you can create a zip/tar.gz archive from it...

Answer (score 1):

No, it is not possible. When Maven encounters multiple matches for a version reference, it uses the highest matching version. [Here](https://docs.oracle.com/middleware/1212/core/MAVEN/maven_version.htm) you can find good explanation how to work with version ranges in maven.

I can suggest other solution for your original task:

1. Create new maven module.
2. Add all projects that you need as a dependencies to this module.
3. Use [maven-dependency-plugin](https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-dependency-plugin/copy-dependencies-mojo.html) to copy dependencies of this module.

[Maven guarantees](https://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-dependency-mechanism.html#Transitive_Dependencies) that one and only one version of each (groupId:artifactId) is used. You can check resolved versions using `mvn dependency:tree`.