# How to pin latest version of a maven artifact while creating a project from archetype

Tags: java, maven, maven-2, maven-3, maven-archetype

I have an archetype that we use to create new projects. At the point of project creation (i.e. when someone executes `mvn archetype:generate`) I want to pin some of the dependencies to `RELEASE` version available at that time (I strongly oppose putting `<version>RELEASE</version>` in POM file).

Is there a way I can make archetype to resolve `RELEASE` version and pin that for some of the libraries.

Only way I solve this problem right now is by releasing new version of archetype every time some of the core libraries are released and then hard coding versions of those in the `archetype-resources/pom.xml`

I did see couple of similar questions but none of the solutions for those work for me.

As I already mentioned, that I want to pin the latest release version available at the time of creating project from archetype. Using `RELEASE means that I can not recreate binaries from same source code as I will end up fetching a different version of dependency.

Let me explain with concrete example.

- I have an archetype with maven co-ordinate `com.my-company:my-awesome-framework:1.0`.
- I have a library with maven co-ordinates `com.my-company:core-lib:1.0`.
- **Developer-1** runs command `mvn archeype:generate my-awesome-framework`. He fills in required details and creates project called `service-foo`.  `service -foo` has dependency `core-lib` and since.
- We add more features to `core-lib` and release version `2.0`
- **Developer-1** build `service-foo` it still builds with `core-lib` version `1.0`. (since he hasn't changed the version the project's POM file. Had I used `<version>RELEASE<version>` for 'core-lib`, this time`service-foo`would have built with version`2.0`of the`core-lib`)
- **Devloper-2** runs `mvn archetype:generate my-awesome-framework`. He fills out required fields and creates a service called `service-bar`. Now this time since `core-lib` version `2.0`. Note that I did not modify `my-awesome-archetype` to update version for `core-lib` inside `archetype-resources\pom.xml`

I hope this clarifies my use case

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I tell Maven to use the latest version of a dependency?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30571/how-do-i-tell-maven-to-use-the-latest-version-of-a-dependency)

Comment: I disagree, this is a uniquely different question -- RELEASE will always pull in the latest release, even after the project is generated.  He wants to pin the version *at generation time*.

Answer (score 0):

I solved this using archetype-post-generate.groovy, script. Maven archetype plugin executes that (if available) after the project has been created. There one can use Maven versions plugin to update to the latest releases.

Here is an example how you can update both versions in properties and in parent project (in Spring Boot in this case):

```
dir = new File(new File(request.outputDirectory), request.artifactId)

def run(String cmd) {
    def process = cmd.execute(null, dir)
    process.waitForProcessOutput((Appendable)System.out, System.err)
    if (process.exitValue() != 0) {
        throw new Exception("Command '$cmd' exited with code: ${process.exitValue()}")
    }
}

run("echo 'Updating to latest Vaadin version...'")
run("mvn versions:update-properties")

run("echo 'Updating to latest Spring Boot version...'")
run("mvn versions:update-parent")
```

The downside is that Eclipse don't seem to execute that script, but in other major IDEs and command line this work just fine.

The groovy script form my [Vaadin + Spring Boot archetype in GitHub](https://github.com/viritin/vaadin-flow-archetypes/blob/master/spring/src/main/resources/META-INF/archetype-post-generate.groovy).