# maven-ant-tasks doesn't resolve the latest artifact version from the local repository

Tags: maven, ant, artifact

probably it will sound like silly question but I'm stuck. I have ant build.xml which has maven-ant-tasks

```
<target name="downloadDependencies">
    <artifact:dependencies filesetId="dependency.fileset" useScope="runtime">
        <dependency groupId="<my_artifact_group_id>" artifactId="<my_artifact_id>" version="latest"/>
    </artifact:dependencies>

    <mkdir dir="${build.dir}/lib" />

    <copy todir="${build.dir}/lib">
        <fileset refid="dependency.fileset" />
        <mapper type="flatten" />
    </copy>
</target>
```

I need to provide the latest version because it's my own artifact, seems like the ant maven task doesn't know to resolve it. The error I get

> BUILD FAILED
>       .../build.xml:20: Unable to resolve artifact: Missing:
>       ----------
>   Try downloading the file manually from the project website.
>
> Then, install it using the command: 
>             mvn install:install-file -DgroupId= -DartifactId= -Dversion=latest -Dpackaging=jar -Dfile=/path/to/file
>
> Alternatively, if you host your own repository you can deploy the file there: 
>             mvn deploy:deploy-file -DgroupId= -DartifactId= -Dversion=latest -Dpackaging=jar -Dfile=/path/to/file -Durl=[url] -DrepositoryId=[id]

**Question**: How can I force the ant maven plugin to resolve the latest version?

Comment: "The error I get" and then it's cut off... What error are you getting exactly? Please edit that into your question.

Comment: I added more details

Answer (score 0):

I think your issue is with how you have published the version

```
mvn install:install-file .... -Dversion=latest ...
```

To the best of my knowledge Maven doesn't have any special handling or a "latest" string. You must explicitly set a valid version number when installing the artifact. For example

```
mvn install:install-file .... -Dversion=1.1 ...
```

Comment: I thought that maven does support this feature
This link explains this stuff pretty good http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30571/how-do-i-tell-maven-to-use-the-latest-version-of-a-dependency

Comment: @Denis It doesn't. I have revised my answer to make that statement more explicit

Comment: Thanks for reply, I got the error. I had to use RELEASE because the dependancy isn't snapshot.