# Maven RELEASE and LATEST version "numbers"

Tags: maven, maven-3

The `-SNAPSHOT` version [qualifier](https://docs.oracle.com/middleware/1212/core/MAVEN/maven_version.htm#A1000676) is well explained in Oracle's *"Understanding Maven Version Numbers"*.

But now I hear there is a [RELEASE](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1172371/8080472) and [LATEST](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1172371/8080472) version "numbers" as well. And at the same news item, that they are deprecated in Maven 3.

What are these RELEASE and LATEST version numbers/notations? Where can I learn more about them?

Comment: The links you included in your question (to [RELEASE](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1172371/8080472) and [LATEST](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1172371/8080472)) provide an extract from a Maven book which describes the behaviour of the RELEASE and LATEST symbolic version identifiers and they also provide a link to the [Maven release notes](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/Maven+3.x+Compatibility+Notes#Maven3.xCompatibilityNotes-PluginMetaversionResolution) describing why they are not supported in Maven v3. Are those links really not sufficient to answer your question?

Comment: The Oracle's Docs about Maven versions is simply out of date and it is related to Maven 2 but it is not valid for Maven 3+ (nor correct). And yes they are depreacted and should not be used anymore...Better use a real version (release) like `1.5.6.8` or a SNAPSHOT version like `6.3.78.3-SNAPSHOT`. There nothing to learn about `RELEASE` and `LATEST` just don't use them anymore...

Comment: Thank you @khmarbaise and @glitch. Indeed this has been confusing for me. The link I included in my question is focused on a different question and includes so many links, I need a terser source for explaining in a bit more focused way the purpose and use of these `RELEASE` and `LATEST` keywords. As for the not learning option, I have inherited a project that relies heavily on `RELEASE` at least. Does that mean that the project is stuck at Maven 2?

Comment: It depends. The question is how the `RELEASE` and `LATEST` are used...better is to change them to real versions...but without a full pom file etc I can't more concrete...Maybe this helps a litter bit further: http://blog.soebes.de/blog/2017/02/04/apache-maven-how-version-comparison-works/

Answer (score 2):

Copying answer from link provided by - glytching

> Internally, Maven 2.x used the special version markers RELEASE and
> LATEST to support automatic plugin version resolution. These
> metaversions were also recognized in the  element for a
>  declaration. For the sake of reproducible builds, Maven 3.x
> no longer supports usage of these metaversions in the POM. As a
> result, users will need to replace occurrences of these metaversions
> with a concrete version.