# How do I get the maven dependency:tree command to show when I'm using a RELEASE version?

Tags: maven, dependencies, versioning

I'm using the maven `dependency:tree` [command](https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-dependency-plugin/tree-mojo.html) to see all my modules and submodules.

We're using a dev=`RELEASE` version model so that we can see our dependencies fail fast. Then we lock in a version when we go to prod.

Our dependency tree goes about four levels deep of modules.

I want a quick way to identify if anything in my pom dependencies contains a `RELEASE` version.

I'd like to be able to use the `dependency:tree` [command](https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-dependency-plugin/examples/resolving-conflicts-using-the-dependency-tree.html) to do this - but unfortunately it resolves all the `RELEASE` versions to the last 'dot' version.

Note this is using Maven 2.

My question is: **How do I get the maven dependency:tree command to show when I'm using a RELEASE version?**

Comment: I doubt that you find much support for this as RELEASE is long deprecated.

Comment: This is maven 2 - could you please provide evidence that RELEASE is deprecated?

Comment: Maybe you should add the Maven version that you are using to your question.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/1172371/927493

Comment: Migrate to Maven 3 as soon as possible..many recent plugins will not with maven 2 anymore...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The trick is - as the comments have pointed out - is to upgrade to Maven 3 - and then use the [Maven Versions Plugin](http://www.mojohaus.org/versions-maven-plugin/) :

This means you have to set the versions explicitly - but you still get the fail-fast behaviour.

See here for more detail:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/48184999/15441