# How do you do fail-fast for grandchild dependencies since RELEASE versioning was deprecated in Maven?

Tags: java, maven

Maven 2.0 allowed the RELEASE versioning model. ie when specifying which version you wanted, you could just say `<version>RELEASE<version>` and it would get the latest for you.

In Maven 3.0 this [has been dropped](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/Maven+3.x+Compatibility+Notes#Maven3.xCompatibilityNotes-PluginMetaversionResolution). The reason they give is that you need to ensure reproducible builds. But this doesn't address the reason that RELEASE was there in the first place.

The point of the RELEASE was to enable fast failures in your build when chaining module dependencies together. If you lock the versions down, then a future failure due to a change in a grandchild module won't get detected until you upgrade the versions. If you use LATEST, then the failing change in the grandchild module gets detected right away.

My question is: **How do you do fail-fast for grandchild dependencies since RELEASE versioning was deprecated in Maven?**

Comment: The special version `RELEASE` mean to use the latest which contradicts reproducibility. And that the reason why it has been deprecated and will produce WARNING's for the [most recent version of Maven](http://maven.apache.org/docs/3.5.2/release-notes.html). The detecting can simply being done by using automated testings which uses versions-maven-plugin to update dependency versions automatically and check if it's working if not do not update the version and information the devs about it...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The trick is to use Maven 3 and the [Maven Versions Plugin](http://www.mojohaus.org/versions-maven-plugin/) :

In particular the following goals could be of use:

- **versions:use-latest-versions** searches the pom for all versions
  which have been a newer version and
  replaces them with the latest
  version.
- **versions:use-latest-releases** searches the pom for all non-SNAPSHOT
  versions which have been a newer
  release and replaces them with the
  latest release version.
- **versions:update-properties** updates properties defined in a
  project so that they correspond to
  the latest available version of
  specific dependencies. This can be
  useful if a suite of dependencies
  must all be locked to one version.

The following other goals are also provided:

- **versions:display-dependency-updates** scans a project's dependencies and
  produces a report of those
  dependencies which have newer
  versions available.
- **versions:display-plugin-updates** scans a project's plugins and
  produces a report of those plugins
  which have newer versions available.
- **versions:update-parent** updates the parent section of a project so
  that it references the newest
  available version. For example, if
  you use a corporate root POM, this
  goal can be helpful if you need to
  ensure you are using the latest
  version of the corporate root POM.
- **versions:update-child-modules** updates the parent section of the
  child modules of a project so the
  version matches the version of the
  current project. For example, if you
  have an aggregator pom that is also
  the parent for the projects that it
  aggregates and the children and
  parent versions get out of sync, this
  mojo can help fix the versions of the
  child modules. (Note you may need to
  invoke Maven with the -N option in
  order to run this goal if your
  project is broken so badly that it
  cannot build because of the version
  mis-match).
- **versions:lock-snapshots** searches the pom for all -SNAPSHOT
  versions and replaces them with the
  current timestamp version of that
  -SNAPSHOT, e.g. -20090327.172306-4
- **versions:unlock-snapshots** searches the pom for all timestamp
  locked snapshot versions and replaces
  them with -SNAPSHOT.
- **versions:resolve-ranges** finds dependencies using version ranges and
  resolves the range to the specific
  version being used.
- **versions:use-releases** searches the pom for all -SNAPSHOT versions
  which have been released and replaces
  them with the corresponding release
  version.
- **versions:use-next-releases** searches the pom for all non-SNAPSHOT
  versions which have been a newer
  release and replaces them with the
  next release version.
- **versions:use-next-versions** searches the pom for all versions
  which have been a newer version and
  replaces them with the next version.
- **versions:commit** removes the pom.xml.versionsBackup files. Forms
  one half of the built-in "Poor Man's
  SCM".
- **versions:revert** restores the pom.xml files from the
  pom.xml.versionsBackup files. Forms
  one half of the built-in "Poor Man's
  SCM".