# Set version aliases in nexus maven repository

Tags: maven-2, nexus

I have own maven2 repository in nexus, for publishing build artifacts.
I'm using maven deploy plugin for uploading artifacts there

Is it possible somehow to add custom aliases(links) to versions inside my repo, so project/script/whatever will use artifacts from repository, can refer to some static version-name(e.g. stable,earlier,development)

And during each publishing of new version to repo, I will update those aliases.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, there's no version aliasing in maven. However, you can use version range for your dependency or use profiles to specify different versions for your builds.

Have a look at this question, so you get the idea what is possible: [How do I tell Maven to use the latest version of a dependency?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30571/how-do-i-tell-maven-to-use-the-latest-version-of-a-dependency)