# How to get the latest RELEASE version of dependencies in maven 3?

Tags: java, maven, dependencies

I am a JS dev. With NPM you can use wildcard or keyword to tell npm to get the latest minor, major...etc 1.2.x .
 Is there a way to do this with **maven 3** ?

```
 <properties>
        <artifact.version>1.2.0-RC1</artifact.version>
        <my-dep.version>1.5.0-RC*</my-dep.version>
    </properties>
```

On build, I would get the latest RC (RC1, RC2...etc) each time I build.

I've found this answer but for Maven 2 :
[How do I tell Maven to use the latest version of a dependency?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30571/how-do-i-tell-maven-to-use-the-latest-version-of-a-dependency?rq=1)

Thanks

Stéphane.

Comment: Your linked answer for Maven 2 should also apply for Maven 3, except that `RELEASE` and `LATEST` have been removed. What about an open ended version range like `[1.5.0.RC,)`.

Comment: I am not very familiar with maven. I ll try this arvo

Comment: Should it be <version>[1.5.0.RC,1.6.0)</version>, to get only 1.5.0 rc but not upperversion (1.6.0 and 1.6.0rc...etc)?

Comment: or [1.5.0.RC,1.6.0-SNAPSHOT)?

Comment: Yeah, i havent noticed that you only want a particular release candidate up to a specific version. Then it should be `[1.5.0-RC1,1.6.0)`

Comment: @Stefdelec Any solution for the same? I am facing the same problem on auto update of maven in my MAC.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As Glains said in comment, this link is fine for MAVEN 3 [How do I tell Maven to use the latest version of a dependency?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30571/how-do-i-tell-maven-to-use-the-latest-version-of-a-dependency?rq=1)

Even the RELEASE keyword.

[1.5.0-RC1,1.6.0)

Comment: Note: This only applies to `<dependencies>`. Support for using this kind of wildcard ranges in `<plugins>` has been removed in 3.x