# Make com.here.platform sdk version in pom.xml generic

Tags: maven, pom.xml, here-olp

How can I mention the version in pom.xml generic ? . Can I make it to download the latest version of dependency automatically ?

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.here.platform</groupId>
    <artifactId>sdk-bom</artifactId>
    <version>1.5.55</version>
    <type>pom</type>
    <scope>import</scope>
  </dependency>
```

Comment: That would be a horrible, horrible idea. The latest version could well have breaking changes.

Comment: how about defining a `bom` with a parent in your module? Just a thought for having a managed dependency then defining versions everywhere.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not quite sure what you mean here, if you want to have multiple declarations of this dependency within a single project use `dependencyManagement` at the projects top level pom. If you simply want to use a variable define a property like so:

```
<properties>
    <com.here.platform.version>1.5.55</com.here.platform.version>
</properties>
```

and then:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.here.platform</groupId>
    <artifactId>sdk-bom</artifactId>
    <version>${com.here.platform.version}</version>
    <type>pom</type>
    <scope>import</scope>
</dependency>
```

Please add more details so we know what you are asking.

Comment: can I make it download the latest version automatically ? Something like <version>LATEST</version>

Comment: LATEST was dropped in maven 3, read this question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30571/how-do-i-tell-maven-to-use-the-latest-version-of-a-dependency/1172805#1172805