# Maven - Always download the latest version of dependency or plugin

Tags: java, maven

In the pom.xml, I always specify the `<version>` of the dependency or plugin I am using.

Is there a way to tell Maven I always want the latest version downloaded without explicitly updating the version number every time?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30571/how-do-i-tell-maven-to-use-the-latest-version-of-a-dependency#1172805

Comment: The official part: https://maven.apache.org/pom.html#Dependency_Version_Requirement_Specification

Comment: @khmarbaise Thank you for the official reference.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you can declear your dependency version like `<version>[1.0.0,)</version>`

it will resolve after 1.0.0 version for your dependency.

Comment: Will this only get the latest version for 1.x.x or will it also update to 2.x.x once available?

Comment: it will update also if 2.x.x  is available for your dependency

Comment: Thank you, it looks like the ranges used in maths/algebra. :)