# Maven not loading SNAPSHOT from local repository

Tags: java, maven

For a REST service environment I am writing the REST server application along with a client library in order to use the same model objects on server and client side.

For local development it would be great if I could include the latest build SNAPSHOT from my local maven repository as current version.

In my `pom.xml` I have

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.mygroup</groupId>
    <artifactId>backoffice-client</artifactId>
    <version>LATEST</version>
</dependency>
```

My local repository holds versions `1.0.0-SNAPSHOT`, `1.0.0` and `1.0.1-SNAPSHOT`.

The imported version in this case is `1.0.0` but I would expect it to be `1.0.1-SNAPSHOT`.

On gradle this is working by using `compile(com.mygroup:backoffice-client:+)`.

I already tried setting `-DignoreSnapshots=false` on maven command line without success.

What can I do to get the latest snapshot from my local repository loaded properly?

Comment: I would look at this answer using the version-plugin: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30571/how-do-i-tell-maven-to-use-the-latest-version-of-a-dependency/1172805#1172805

Comment: The `LATEST` is long time deprecated and should not used anymore....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's because your are using the word **SNAPSHOT**, which is a keyword for Maven.

As described [here](https://docs.oracle.com/middleware/1212/core/MAVEN/maven_version.htm#MAVEN401), *Maven treats the SNAPSHOT qualifier differently from all others. If a version number is followed by -SNAPSHOT, then Maven considers it the "as-yet-unreleased" version of the associated MajorVersion, MinorVersion, or IncrementalVersion.*

So for Maven the "snapshot" is not the latest **stable** release, which is the one that is looking for when you tell him to take the *latest* release.

Comment: I read this part but didn't realize that `LATEST` requires a stable release. Is there a way to tell maven to cover unstable releases as well?

Comment: Not with the LATEST keyword, you have to specify that version into the version number into your pom, as said by @Damith in his answer

Answer (score 1):

Your workaround is add the exact version number to your dependency.

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.mygroup</groupId>
    <artifactId>backoffice-client</artifactId>
    <version>1.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
</dependency>
```

for the question why its not automatically loaded when you add LATEST, @Leviand's explanation is correct.