# How to find out the latest jar dependency available in artifactory?

Tags: java, maven, maven-3, jfrog-cli

How to find out the latest jar dependency available in artifactory by JFrog based on GroupId and ArtifactId.

For example: The below dependency  is the latest available .But how the value 5.1.0.RELEASE can be obtained through code?

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-core</artifactId>
    <version>5.1.0.RELEASE</version>
</dependency>
```

I have searched from JFrog rest api.But didn't found clear document

The answer in the below link applies mostly to maven 2 .

[How do I tell Maven to use the latest version of a dependency?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30571/how-do-i-tell-maven-to-use-the-latest-version-of-a-dependency)

Comment: Why do you need that? What kind of problem are you trying to solve?

Comment: There is a specific api endpoint to perform exactly what you are looking for, but it requires artifactory pro

Comment: @khmarbaise i need to scan a list of jar(from maven tree)and list all the jars that has an upgrade availble.mvn versions:display-dependency-updates is not helping out as it is not giving details on the upgrade for transitive dependencies,