# How to fetch the latest released version of a dependency included in my pom.xml

Tags: maven-3

Instead of manually changing the version each time, i want the maven to load the released jar version automatically.

I'm using Eclipse with embedded Maven version  3.5.4

Could you anyone suggest on how to resolve this ?

I have tried LATEST and RELEASE keywords in 
LATEST
But it does not work.
If i use version range like 
[1.70.4,) it loads the snapshot version which i do NOT want

i have added the below mentioned dependency  in my pom.xml

```
      <dependency>
        <groupId>com.xxx.portal</groupId>
        <artifactId>portal-xxx-integrationtests</artifactId>
        <version>1.70.4</version>
        <classifier>tests</classifier>
        <type>test-jar</type>
        <scope>test</scope>
      </dependency>
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I tell Maven to use the latest version of a dependency?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30571/how-do-i-tell-maven-to-use-the-latest-version-of-a-dependency)

Comment: possible duplicate of .. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30571/how-do-i-tell-maven-to-use-the-latest-version-of-a-dependency/1172805#1172805