# Failed to collect dependencies at com.itextpdf:itext7-core:pom:RELEASE

Tags: java, maven, itext

I am trying to create a pdf report using itextpdf library. As it is instructed in [the official documentation](https://itextpdf.com/en/resources/installation-guides/installing-itext-7-java), I did add the following dependency in my pom.xml :

```
<properties>
   <itext.version>RELEASE</itext.version>
</properties>
<dependencies>
    <!-- add all iText 7 modules -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.itextpdf</groupId>
        <artifactId>itext7-core</artifactId>
        <version>${itext.version}</version>
        <type>pom</type>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

To make sure everything is neat and clean, I deleted my .m2/repository directory `$rm -R .m2/repository` and did run afterwwards `$mvn clean compile` in my project home directory. I got then the following error :

```
org.apache.maven.lifecycle.LifecycleExecutionException: Failed to execute goal on project business-project: Could not resolve dependencies for project myproject:business-project:jar:1.1-SNAPSHOT: Failed to collect dependencies at com.itextpdf:itext7-core:pom:RELEASE
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleDependencyResolver.getDependencies (LifecycleDependencyResolver.java:269)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleDependencyResolver.resolveProjectDependencies (LifecycleDependencyResolver.java:147)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.ensureDependenciesAreResolved (MojoExecutor.java:248)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:202)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:156)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:148)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject (LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:117)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject (LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:81)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.builder.singlethreaded.SingleThreadedBuilder.build (SingleThreadedBuilder.java:56)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.execute (LifecycleStarter.java:128)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute (DefaultMaven.java:305)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute (DefaultMaven.java:192)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.execute (DefaultMaven.java:105)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.execute (MavenCli.java:957)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.doMain (MavenCli.java:289)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.main (MavenCli.java:193)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0 (Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke (NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke (DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke (Method.java:498)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launchEnhanced (Launcher.java:282)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launch (Launcher.java:225)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.mainWithExitCode (Launcher.java:406)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.main (Launcher.java:347)
Caused by: org.apache.maven.project.DependencyResolutionException: Could not resolve dependencies for project myproject:business-project:jar:1.1-SNAPSHOT: Failed to collect dependencies at com.itextpdf:itext7-core:pom:RELEASE
```

This the output of `$mvn dependency:tree` :

```
[INFO] -------------------< myproject:business-project >--------------------
[INFO] Building Business Layer 1.1-SNAPSHOT                        [3/4]
[INFO] --------------------------------[ jar ]---------------------------------
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Reactor Summary for myproject 1.1-SNAPSHOT:
[INFO] 
[INFO] my project ......................................... SUCCESS [  0.921 s]
[INFO] DB .......................................... SUCCESS [  0.108 s]
[INFO] Business Layer .............................. FAILURE [  0.234 s]
[INFO] Web Application ............................. SKIPPED
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time:  1.662 s
[INFO] Finished at: 2020-02-21T20:07:06+01:00
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal on project business-project: Could not resolve dependencies for project myproject:business-project:jar:1.1-SNAPSHOT: Failed to collect dependencies at com.itextpdf:itext7-core:pom:RELEASE: Failed to read artifact descriptor for com.itextpdf:itext7-core:pom:RELEASE: Failed to resolve version for com.itextpdf:itext7-core:pom:RELEASE: Could not find metadata com.itextpdf:itext7-core/maven-metadata.xml in local (/Users/MyComputer/.m2/repository) -> [Help 1]
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch.
[ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
[ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/DependencyResolutionException
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] After correcting the problems, you can resume the build with the command
[ERROR]   mvn <args> -rf :business-project
```

Running `$mvn -v` I get :

```
Apache Maven 3.6.3 (cecedd343002696d0abb50b32b541b8a6ba2883f)
Maven home: /usr/local/Cellar/maven/3.6.3/libexec
Java version: 1.8.0_101, vendor: Oracle Corporation, runtime: /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_101.jdk/Contents/Home/jre
Default locale: de_DE, platform encoding: UTF-8
OS name: "mac os x", version: "10.14.3", arch: "x86_64", family: "mac"
```

My nexus server configured in my settings.xml :

```
<mirrors>

        <mirror>
                                               <id>public</id>
                                               <mirrorOf>*</mirrorOf>
                                               <name>Central Repositories of internal repository manager Nexus</name>
                                                <url>http://nexus-server:8081/nexus/content/repositories/public</url>
                               </mirror>
    </mirrors>
```

How can I fix this problem please? Thank you.

Comment: Can you post the output of `mvn -v`, and `mvn dependency:tree`?

Comment: @PiRocks done! :)

Comment: Are you sure that you are connected to the internet? Have you tried backing up your `.m2` and then deleting it?

Comment: Have you also considered using there repo: 
```
<repositories>
  <repository>
    <id>itext-releases</id>
    <name>iText Repository - releases</name>
    <url>https://repo.itextsupport.com/releases</url>
  </repository>
</repositories>
```

Comment: @PiRocks Yes I am connected to the internet and did backup my .m2 as you said. One thing to mention is that the server I am connecting to is a local nexus server. Please check the post.

Comment: See my answer. The version you have defined via property does simply not exist....etc.

Answer (score 6):

I don't understand exactly what you are trying to do but based on the given information I suppose you are trying to import the pom file as a so called [BOM (Bill Of Material)](https://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-dependency-mechanism.html#Importing_Dependencies). The issue you have is that you are trying to define a `pom` type as a dependency which will not work cause it is nothing what you can put on the classpath. Furthermore the given version, which you have [defined via the property does simply not exist in Central repository](https://search.maven.org/artifact/com.itextpdf/itext7-core).

The trick is to go via `dependencyManagement` like this:

```
<dependencyManagement>
    <dependencies>
      <dependency>
        <groupId>com.itextpdf</groupId>
        <artifactId>itext7-core</artifactId>
        <version>7.1.10</version>
        <type>pom</type>
        <scope>import</scope>
      </dependency>
   </dependencies>
</dependencyManagement>
```

Afterwards you can use now the dependencies which have been defined in that BOM file as this:

```
<dependencies>
  <dependency>
      <groupId>com.itextpdf</groupId>
      <artifactId>barcodes</artifactId>
  </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

All of the dependencies in that bom can now simply being used by defining them without the version which is controlled by the bom file in the `dependencyManagement`. This is an elegant way to manage dependencies at a single location via the bom file. You only need to change the version of the bom file and that's it.

Comment: I am getting this error : Project build error: Non-resolvable import POM: Failure to find com.itextpdf:itext7-core:pom:7.1.10 in http://nexus-server:8081/nexus/content/repositories/public was cached in the local repository, resolution will not be reattempted until the update interval of public has elapsed or updates are forced

Comment: On the other hand I don't want to import as a BOM as what you mentioned, I want to include as a .jar.

Comment: There are two things here. First your nexus server seemed to be configured wrong...Furthermore I would try to build via `mvn clean package -U` and furthermore you have not read the docs nor read my explanations. This artifact is not a jar it's a pom only...and can't be used as a jar....the other artifacts like the one from my example (barcodes) is one...

Comment: ArtifactId `itext7-core` only exists as a `.pom`, and exactly for the reason that @khmarbaise has 100% correctly answered. Upvoting. (I am QA Engineer at iText Software)

Comment: @AmedeeVanGasse If you are one of them (iText Software) you should check the docs https://itextpdf.com/en/resources/installation-guides/installing-itext-7-java cause the example shows a version `RELEASE` which is not allowed anymore for a very long time. The following `which will ensure you install the current release versions of the iText 7 modules` is simply wrong and will produce WARNINGs in builds`. Furthermore the explanation on the page about "Adding all Modules" is simply wrong. As I described using a BOM has to be done as I described. This user guide should be fixed.

Comment: I would have also reconsidered to name the artifact something like `itext7-bom` instead of `itext7-core` to make it more clear what it is intended for ...

Comment: @khmarbaise `RELEASE` is a metaversion that resolves to the latest release number, when using *Maven 2*. It also means that the documentation doesn't have to be changed each time a new version is released. However, that metaversion has been dropped in *Maven 3*. It also means that for every new release, that page on the website needs to be updated too. I will report this as a content bug for our web team.

Comment: Changing the artifact name of an already released artifact could of course introduce other issues, nevertheless, duly noted.

Comment: See also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30571/how-do-i-tell-maven-to-use-the-latest-version-of-a-dependency/1172371#1172371

Comment: @AmedeeVanGasse Of course you can not change already released artifacts (releases are immutable) but it would have been a good idea to do that in advance earlier. But it might be done for the next major release?

Comment: I'll pass the message.

Comment: Also, 'iText Core' is a product name, so that will most likely not change. *If* a change is made, then `itext-core-bom` as artifactname is more likely.

Comment: Or, you know what? You can submit a pull request on the GitHub repo!

Comment: All technical content will soon (ish) move away from the main website to a separate knowledge base (probably something something Confluence) but I don't know thw time frame so I don't know if the web team is going to update the current page on the website or if they are going to put it right in the knowledge base.

Comment: @khmarbaise I tried with the `pom.xml` snippets you posted and then I get errors: `[ERROR] [ERROR] Some problems were encountered while processing the POMs:
[ERROR] 'dependencies.dependency.version' for com.itextpdf:kernel:jar is missing. @ line 51, column 17`. So a version number is still required even when you put the BOM in `dependencyManagement`.

Comment: And that essentially makes the `dependencyManagement` redundant.

Comment: Just for the record: I know that you are an Apache Maven contributor, so I will assume that you know better than I do, I'm just copy/pasting what I see when I run the `mvn` command.

Comment: @khmarbaise your answer here inspired me to ask a related question on the Code Review Stack Exchange, you may want to take a look: https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/238437/add-junit4-as-a-test-dependency-to-a-maven-project