# Is it possible for one Maven module to have a version-less dependency to another module?

Tags: java, build, maven-3, dependency-management

I have multiple Maven modules, let's say `A, B, C` and I also have a module `D`.

Can module `D` have dependencies to `A, B, C` without explicitly setting their version? In other words, I'd like module `D` to be built with the latest code of the other modules.

Comment: If you have a multi module build you can use `${project.version}`..as version for the dependencies on other modules.. that is one solution. The other is to define a dependencyManagement in root and so that means to omit the version tag in the appropriate modules...

Comment: It could be possible to make a hacky way. Just use a SNAPSHOT version like `1.0-SNAPSHOT` which means it's always the latest version via `mvn -U package`... but it's not reproducible...

Answer (score 0):

You could just set a minimum version of modules A,B,C in your D module, as per https://docs.oracle.com/middleware/1212/core/MAVEN/maven_version.htm#MAVEN402

like you can set your dependency version as [1.5,) wich means any version greater than or equal to 1.5

Or you could use "RELEASE" versions, for more information on this please see this other SO question where Rich gives a very good explanation:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/1172371/14650195

Comment: The linked reference is out of date in many ways. A version range might not the best idea. The suggested `RELEASE` version will not work and it deprecated for a very long time ...